# Neural Network - Should I Remove All Derived / Calculated Variables?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using a neural network to control the movement of a character in a game.  I've currently got a huge amount of dimensions and in the interest of trimming them to improve storage and code manageability, I'm considering removing all derived variables i.e. any variable which can be calculated from data already sent into to the network.

An example of this would be the relationship between a) position, b) velocity, and c) acceleration along a path.  Currently, I send the last 50 data points of all three to the NN to help it decide its next movement.  However, I wonder if system control / error could be minimized just as easily by sending only position.  Theoretically the neural network should be able to derive the velocity and acceleration at a point in time entirely on it's own given the position history.

Generally, is dimension reduction in this capacity recommended?  Why or why not?

I know the oft recommendation in this scenario is just to test it and see what happens, but in this case there are so many variables here that it would take days to test, so I was hoping to hear anyone's experience given this type of situation and what they surmise the general rule to be.

Bonus question--would this assessment / decision be different for a neural network (intent on mapping functions to data) as opposed to a random forest (seems to use more of a nearest neighbor approach).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Implement PCA to reduce the number of features.  They reduced features will have unusual units like [position*velocity*acceleration].  However, if you do PCA correctly you can retain a feature set that has 99% variance of the original set.

Then use the new feature set in your NN.

Reducing dimensions is recommended to speed-up algorithms because, as you observed, there is a lot of similarity between your features.